Woman living in an apartment taking self-portraits everyday (from 1990 to 2005)
And then suddenly there's this monster who hates the flash and the woman uses it to escape the monster... and by self-portraits.. it's like a Polaroid/instax thingy. So she had to go away and then at the end I think she was given flowers by some guy and that guy is apparently the monster or something. Please help! 
Edit1: I think the reason why she came back to the apartment/building is because there was a news that everything's fine now. And no, it wasn't Shutter. It was about a monster not a ghost.
Edit2: It certainly wasn't any of the movies mentioned here.
Edit3: It wasn't Mimic/2 either. There weren't any kids in that movie (well I don't remember any) but I think the woman's Mother was present and there's another man I think or I'm probably making it up. sigh She has this collage of her everyday photos attached on her wall.
Edit4: I do remember something about that monster destroying the whole floor or probably the whole building. She escaped through an elevator. (I probably made up the elevator part, sorry).

To me this sounds a bit like the game Fatal Frame. Do you remember if the actors are asian? I think I've read about a few japanese movies with this camera/monster formula.

I don't think that the actors were asian. Not sure if she was English or American either :/ | I skimmed the article about Fatal Frame, not sure if I read it right but the movie that I'm looking for doesn't store the monsters in the camera, it's just that the monsters are annoyed by it (I think that they really hate it). The woman just used it to get away~ and then after that everything's a blur, the only ending I can remember is that there was a news about the apartment being fine/clean again and that it was safe to come back. And then she receives flowers...

Is it Mimic 2? In the movie large insect like creature kills human and are pretty much like monsters. And in ending savior was revealed to be an insect creature, who gives flower or something similar to the heroine. Heroine has camera and clicks pictures to much. Specially after her failed dates, she takes her self-photos.

Not this either D:

This sounds like Shutter. From IMDB:

A newly married couple discovers disturbing, ghostly images in photographs they develop after a tragic accident. Fearing the manifestations may be connected, they investigate and learn that some mysteries are better left unsolved.

At the end of the movie, we discover Ben is the cause of the manifestation which is now indelibly attached to him like a monkey on his back ... literally.

Don't think so. Movie is about ghoust not monster.

@AnkitSharma ... Oh, she's a monster ... terrorizes them quite a bit. No worries.
